# How to add conditions in PHP API for Parse

Tags: php, mongodb, api, curl, parse-platform

I am building a mobile interaction game where based on user actions, he is assigned good or bad points and gets notifications and so on.

I have a PARSE collection in which there are four fields (among other fields):

```
- GoodPoints
- EvilPoints
- PlayerID
- deviceToken
```

Using Parse API I want a query which will send notification only if player is "good" (goodPoints > evil Points). I am unsure on how to write a query for this using PHP Parse API.

I currently have:

```
$pushPayload = json_encode(array(
    "where" => array(
        'playerId' => $playerId
        //here I need to add a condition which says goodPoints > evilPoints
     ),
     "data" => array("alert" => "You have turned good!")
));
//..followed by curl call to PARSE API URL..
```

The above query and subsequent cURL call hits the parse collection, finds the devicetoken of the player and sends him the notification. However I want to add additional condition to find record only if userID matches and goodPoints > evilPoints.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? I think the query is in MongoDB style, but I cannot seem to get it right. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using: https://www.parse.com/

[Query page](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#queries)

If so, then I think it's going to be something like:

```
--data-urlencode 'where={"GoodPoints":{"$gt":"EvilPoints"}}'
```

Comment: didnt work! :( `{"where":{"playerId":"Buzzer","GoodPoints":{"$gt":"EvilPoints"}},"data":{"alert":"You are Good!!"}}`

Comment: Ah - yes that looks for the literal string "EvilPoints" OK, possibly: where={"GoodPoints":{"$gt":{"key":"EvilPoints"}}}

Comment: Thank you for answering...unfortunately that failed as well `fail with non value`..maybe its a parse API issue...

Comment: Ah. OK, hopefully somebody will pop up with a solution for you.

Comment: Maybe this: {"where" : "this.GoodPoints > this.EvilPoints" } But even if it does work, it's likely to be very slow